# OAuth2 Authentication for connecting to EWS Server using Aspose is not working

Tags: c#, oauth-2.0, exchangewebservices, aspose

I am very new to C# development and in my learning stage.
I'm currently working on upgrading the EWS Authentication from basic to Oauth authentication.
Following is my code

```
using JsonConvert = Newtonsoft.Json.JsonConvert;
using Aspose.Email.Clients;
using Aspose.Email.Common.Utils;
using Aspose.Email.Tests.TestUtils;
using Newtonsoft.Json;
using System;
using System.IO;
using System.Net;
using System.Text;

namespace TestNS
{
    /// <summary>
    /// Azure resource owner password credential (ROPC) token provider
    /// https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/v2-oauth-ropc
    /// https://portal.azure.com
    /// https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/graph-explorer/#
    /// token parser https://jwt.io
    /// </summary>
    internal class AzureROPCTokenProvider : ITokenProvider
    {
        private const string uriFormat = "https://login.microsoftonline.com/{0}/oauth2/v2.0/token";
        private const string bodyFormat =
            "client_id={0}" +
            "&scope={1}" +
            "&username={2}" +
            "&password={3}" +
            "&grant_type={4}";

        private readonly string scope;
        private const string grant_type = "password";
        private readonly object tokenSyncObj = new object();
        private OAuthToken token;
        private readonly string tenant;
        private readonly string clientId;
        private readonly string clientSecret;
        private readonly string userName;
        private readonly string password;

        /// <summary>
        /// Initializes a new instance of the <see cref="AzureROPCTokenProvider"/> class
        /// </summary>
        /// <param name="tenant"></param>
        /// <param name="clientId"></param>
        /// <param name="clientSecret"></param>
        /// <param name="scope"></param>
        /// <param name="userName"></param>
        /// <param name="password"></param>
        /// <param name="scopeAr"></param>
        public AzureROPCTokenProvider(
            string tenant, 
            string clientId, 
            string clientSecret, 
            string userName, 
            string password,
            string[] scopeAr)
        {
            this.tenant = tenant;
            this.clientId = clientId;
            this.clientSecret = clientSecret;
            this.userName = userName;
            this.password = password;
            this.scope = string.Join(" ", scopeAr);
        }

        /// <summary>
        /// Gets oAuth access token. 
        /// </summary>
        /// <param name="ignoreExistingToken">
        /// If ignoreExistingToken is true, requests new token from a server. Otherwise behaviour is depended on whether token exists or not.
        /// If token exists and its expiration date is not expired returns current token, otherwise requests new token from a server.
        /// </param>
        /// <returns>Returns oAuth access token</returns>
        public virtual OAuthToken GetAccessToken(bool ignoreExistingToken)
        {
            lock (tokenSyncObj)
            {
                if (this.token != null && !this.token.Expired && !ignoreExistingToken)
                    return this.token;
                token = null;
                string uri = string.Format(uriFormat, string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(tenant) ? "common" : tenant);
                HttpWebRequest request = (HttpWebRequest)HttpWebRequest.Create(uri);
                string body = string.Format(bodyFormat,
                    HttpUtility.UrlEncode(clientId),
                    HttpUtility.UrlEncode(scope),
                    HttpUtility.UrlEncode(userName),
                    HttpUtility.UrlEncode(password),
                    HttpUtility.UrlEncode(grant_type));
                byte[] bytes = Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(body);
                request.Method = "POST";
                request.ContentType = "application/x-www-form-urlencoded";
                request.ContentLength = bytes.Length;
                MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream(bytes);
                using (Stream requestStream = request.GetRequestStream())
                    requestStream.Write(bytes, 0, bytes.Length);
                HttpWebResponse response = (HttpWebResponse)request.GetResponse();
                StringBuilder responseText = new StringBuilder();
                bytes = new byte[1024];
                int read = 0;
                using (Stream stream = response.GetResponseStream())
                {
                    while ((read = stream.Read(bytes, 0, bytes.Length)) > 0)
                        responseText.Append(Encoding.ASCII.GetString(bytes, 0, read));
                }
                string jsonString = responseText.ToString();
                AzureTokenResponse t = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<AzureTokenResponse>(jsonString);
                token = new OAuthToken(
                    t.access_token,
                    TokenType.AccessToken,
                    DateTime.Now.AddSeconds(t.expires_in));
                return token;
            }
        }

        /// <summary>
        /// Gets oAuth access token.
        /// If token exists and its expiration date is not expired returns current token, otherwise requests new token from a server.
        /// </summary>
        /// <returns>Returns oAuth access token</returns>
        public OAuthToken GetAccessToken()
        {
            return GetAccessToken(false);
        }

        /// <summary>
        /// Performs application-defined tasks associated with freeing, releasing, or resetting unmanaged resources.
        /// </summary>
        public virtual void Dispose()
        {
        }
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// A success response contains a JSON OAuth 2.0 response with the following parameters.
    /// </summary>
    public class AzureTokenResponse
    {
        /// <summary>
        /// The requested access token. The calling web service can use this token to authenticate to the receiving web service.
        /// </summary>
        public string access_token { get; set; }

        /// <summary>
        /// Indicates the token type value. The only type that Azure AD supports is Bearer For more information about bearer tokens, 
        /// see The OAuth 2.0 Authorization Framework: Bearer Token Usage (RFC 6750).
        /// </summary>
        public string token_type { get; set; }

        /// <summary>
        /// How long the access token is valid (in seconds).
        /// </summary>
        public int expires_in { get; set; }

        /// <summary>
        /// How long the access token is valid (in seconds).
        /// </summary>
        public int ext_expires_in { get; set; }

        /// <summary>
        /// The time when the access token expires. 
        /// The date is represented as the number of seconds from 1970-01-01T00:00:00Z UTC until the expiration time.
        /// This value is used to determine the lifetime of cached tokens.
        /// </summary>
        public int expires_on { get; set; }

        /// <summary>
        /// The App ID URI of the receiving web service.
        /// </summary>
        public string resource { get; set; }

        /// <summary>
        /// If an access token was returned, this parameter lists the scopes the access token is valid for.
        /// </summary>
        public string scope { get; set; }

        /// <summary>
        /// Issued if the original scope parameter included the openid scope.
        /// </summary>
        public string id_token { get; set; }

        /// <summary>
        /// Issued if the original scope parameter included offline_access.
        /// </summary>
        public string refresh_token { get; set; }
    }
}

ITokenProvider tokenProvider = new AzureROPCTokenProvider(
    "Tenant",
    "ClientId",
    "ClientSecret",
    "EMail",
    "Password",
    scopes);

const string mailboxUri = "https://outlook.office365.com/ews/exchange.asmx";
ICredentials credentials = new OAuthNetworkCredential(tokenProvider);
using (IEWSClient ewsClient = EWSClient.GetEWSClient(mailboxUri, credentials))
{

}
```

However, am getting an error response as below

```
System.Net.WebException
  HResult=0x80131509
  Message=The remote server returned an error: (400) Bad Request.
  Source=System
  StackTrace:
   at System.Net.HttpWebRequest.GetResponse()
   at DataLoadLibrary.Emai.AzureROPCTokenProvider.GetAccessToken(Boolean ignoreExistingToken) in C:\path\to\file\DataLoadLibrary\Email\AzureROPCTokenProvider .cs:line 97
   at DataLoadLibrary.Emai.AzureROPCTokenProvider.GetAccessToken() inC:\path\to\file\DataLoadLibrary\Email\AzureROPCTokenProvider .cs:line 123
   at #=zh9Fqfcq_HoOXkObKc3_xqZJZ5tEDCTrUjh8nD$EvlR1sjwBuAg==.GetWebRequest(Uri #=zYomVKA4=)
   at System.Web.Services.Protocols.SoapHttpClientProtocol.Invoke(String methodName, Object[] parameters)
   at #=z59FR9EVW5_PdyTyl2BGNIgxEQwbI$$thui3I5Af7oPUiZ1$E9A==.GetFolder(GetFolderType GetFolder1)
   at Aspose.Email.Clients.Exchange.WebService.EWSClient.GetEWSClient(String mailboxUri, ICredentials credentials, WebProxy proxy)
```

By going through the code I could find that it is not using the client secret which passed to the class. Then I have modified the body `HttpUtility.UrlEncode(ClientSecret));`. Unfortunately I am getting the same exception

Answer (score 1):

Modern authentication (i.e. oAuth2 ) has been supported by EWS. Please read the following Aspose.Email article for more detail.
[Access Mail Services using OAuth](https://docs.aspose.com/email/net/access-mail-services-using-oauth/)

You can download full code examples to use different permission types of modern authentication with EWS client from here:

With Delegated authentication - [EWSModernAuthenticationDelegated.zip](https://www.dropbox.com/s/trqr0g0iqu4v56k/EWSModernAuthenticationDelegated.zip?dl=0)

With Application authentication - [EWSModernAuthenticationApp.zip](https://www.dropbox.com/s/1noh80cw40leqrq/EWSModernAuthenticationApp.zip?dl=0)

Modern authentication with IMAP and SMTP clients - [EWSModernAuthenticationImapSmtp.zip](https://www.dropbox.com/s/rcexmtyx2wxjjhv/EWSModernAuthenticationImapSmtp.zip?dl=0)

I work with Aspose as Developer Evangelist.

Comment: I had already gone through this implementation and it was not working because it is not using the client's secret. Instead its using username & password.

Comment: I have modified the post and attached code examples. Hope this helps you.

Comment: Not able to access the link; Getting this message "Sorry, this file is private. Only visible to topic owner and staff members."

Comment: My apologies, I have uploaded the source code at Dropbox. You can get it now.

Comment: Which version can be chosen for Microsoft.Extensions.configuration if am using .NET 4.5 version

Comment: Please note that Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration isn't supported by the .NET Framework 4.5.